# Example of simply connected space that is not Hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology

Can someone please give me an example of a simply connected space that is not Hausdorff? The only examples that I can think of are Hausdorff.

Thank you.

Comment: Any indiscrete space with more than two points is simply connected (even contractible) and not Hausdorff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb R$ with the cofinite topology is simply connected and not Hausdorff. [Here](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2008&task=show_msg&msg=1830.0001) is a proof.

Comment: I guess that the difficult part in all these questions is to *prove* that the spaces are simply-connected.

Comment: @AlexM. sorry, you're perfectly right.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Take the quotient $L$ of $\mathbb{R} \times \{0,1\}$ by the equivalence $(t,0) \simeq (t,1)$ for $t>0$  -- the line $L$ with a double negative part. Then $L$ is not Hausdorff but simply connected.  Note that the similarly defined line with a double origin is not Hausdorff and also not simply connected.